# Sessions vs Configure at CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-2.3

I saw some codes on internet which in order to check the permissions to access a concrete action, they use the `Configure::read` function in this way:

```
public function action1(){
    if(!Configure::read('isAdmin')){
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'depots', 'action' => 'status'));
    }

    //whatever
}
```

I was wondering, which is the difference between using `Configure::read` and `Configure:write` for this purpose and using `$this->Session->read()` and `$this->Session->write()`?

Which is a better way to check it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Using the AuthComponent

If you make use of the built-in [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html), CakePHP will store details of the currently logged-in user inside the session.

### Getting properties of the currently logged-in User

Once logged in, you can access the information of the Used (e.g. role_id) via the AuthComponent. This can be done *anywhere* (also inside your Views or Models if desired);

For example;

```
if (123 === AuthComponent::user('role_id')) {
    debug('hello admin user');
}
```

Or, inside a Controller:

```
if (123 === $this->Auth->user('role_id')) {
    debug('hello admin user');
}
```

[Accessing the logged in user](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)

However, to dont have to repeat the group-id everywhere, it's best to creat a method for this (e.g inside your AppController);

```
/**
 * Checks if the currently logged in user is an admin
 *
 * @return bool  true if the current user is an admin
 */
protected function isAdmin()
{
    // probably best to make the id configurable (Configure::write())?
    return (123 === $this->Auth->user('role_id'));
}
```

### Access control

To use a 'simple' authorisation, you can create your own `isAuthorized()` action in your Controller, which will allow you to block access to specific actions, based on the properties of the currently logged-in user;

[Using ControllerAuthorize](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you would put the user role in the Configure array, as it is intended to contain application wide settings.

Personaly I have a table in my database that contain the roles. Although some roles may be added to it, there are some that I never modify (typically the administrator role). 
This allows me to store its value as an application parameter in Configure and check for it later:

bootstrap.php

```
Configure :: write('administrator.role_id', 1);
```

TestController:

```
if($this->Auth->user('role_id') == Configure :: read('administrator.role_id'))
{
    //do things specific to admin role
}
```

That said if the user role is stored dynamically in one way or another in Configure, it could probably work as well, but that's probably not the more elegant solution.

Comment: I get the data dynamically, should I use sessions then?